# Access and load symfony Dependency Injection Container outside the project?

Tags: kernel, symfony

Outside the MyProject symfony project dir structure (one level higher than it) I use a simple file for testing:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper;

require __DIR__.'/MyProject/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/MyProject/app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();

echo '<br/>__NAMESPACE__ = '.__NAMESPACE__;
echo '<br/>__DIR__ = '.__DIR__;

$vd = new VarDumper();

dump($kernel->getContainer());
//prints "null"
```

I'd like to load a container with its config included in it. For instance, I wanted to test my databse Entities, access Repositories and so on.

How can I load and access the fully useful **DI Container** here (just like it's available in a controller)? Is there an easy way for doing this?

Or, maybe, speaking more specifically, when I want to load my **config/config.yml** file by e.g.:

```
$loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__));
$loader->load(__DIR__.'/MyProject/app/config/config.yml');
```

I need previously to have all bundles (registered in the AppKernel's - above $kernel var - registerBundles() method) be loaded by the container. How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**: so now it's working, even copy of AppKernel is no longer necessery (so I removed it).
The problem after booting (`$kernel->boot();`) the kernel was with auto-loading annotations. I had to register them manually with the `Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry`:

```
AnnotationRegistry::registerAutoloadNamespace('Doctrine\ORM\Mapping' => __DIR__.'/MyProject/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping');
```

Comment: Have you considered functional testing? https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#functional-tests

Comment: Yeah... This file needs to be outside the project, not a part of it (even if these are tests), so that it not messes around with the GIT project. But thx.

Comment: You can try booting the kernel but I suspect you will just have other problems.

Comment: Yes, I did boot it. I even created a copy of the AppKernel file, removed one of my bundles that caused a problem: an inner entity couldn't load a Doctrine's annotation (but not needed for my testing). Actually, finally I was successful with it after it. Just not quite happy with this "copy of AppKernel" solution... Besides, I cannot use Doctrine due to this "The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity" could not be auto-loaded" issue...